# softlayer User_Customer function changeUsername returns not supported

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the softLayer python API to change a username.

```
 new_creds = {
       'username': new_username,
       'password': new_password
   }
   rc = client['User_Customer'].changeUsername(new_creds, id=user_id)
```

However I get the following exception:
...

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 392, in call_handler
return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 360, in call
return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 263, in call
return self.transport(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 195, in __call__
raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(Client): Function ("changeUsername") is not a valid method for this service
```

Is `changeUsername` not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the **SoftLayer_User_Customer::changeUsername** method is no longer supported. An issue is going to be reported in order to remove it from the SLDN documentation.